# Diamond (♦) moderators with low reputation on this site?

Tags: discussion, support

I just noticed a new "diamond" moderator. Welcome!

Would you mind telling us a bit about yourself? It doesn't appear that you have been active on physics.SE before; we'd like to know a bit more about you than is shown in your profile. How did you become a moderator on this site?

Comment: I believe that Jaydies is a member of the Stack Exchange team, rather than [a moderator for this site in particular](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). If you poke around in the blog you can generally find the welcome for these people.

Comment: Link to user page: http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/10877/jaydles

Comment: @dmckee thanks. I didn't realize there were "global" moderators as I never saw any on this site until just now. The "member for 2 years, reputation 101" threw me a bit.

Comment: So... can we close/delete this question?

Comment: There's a few team members around, including [Shog9](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/2911/shog9), [Oded](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/23068/oded), [Grace Note](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/4826/grace-note), [Geoff Dalgas](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/users/2/geoff-dalgas), and others.

Comment: For the record, there's no way there would be a new site moderator without an election, and you'd hear about an election.

Comment: @DavidZ - that is why I was so surprised and confused.

Comment: @DavidZ Out of curiosity, when is the next election?

Comment: @JamalS there isn't one scheduled. Elections are held whenever the existing mod team decides they need to expand (in consultation with the SE community team), not at fixed times. (Hypothetically, if the community at large thought that more moderators were needed even though the existing moderators didn't, that could spur a meta discussion that could lead to a new election being held.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the new diamond moderator is a SE team member, not a [Phys.SE moderator](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators).

[Here](http://stackexchange.com/about/team) is a list of SE team members (using real names rather than usernames).

Most moderating on Phys.SE is done by Phys.SE moderators, but 
SE team members do help out from time to time.

SE team members also have other tasks, such as, e.g. developing SE software and finding bugs.

For the record: Currently Phys.SE moderators have handled around 10k flags, while SE team members have handled around 70 flags.

Comment: Is there any information about the temporal distribution of those 70 flags? I.e. 50 of those flags before 2012 vs. evenly spread since the start of beta?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I've a vague feeling that it has been happening less in the last year or so. It's not often that there is a team member on the "recent moderator activity page". Mostly just us chickens.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty none of those 70 were more recent than July 2014, from what I'm seeing. (It's _possible_ I could be misinterpreting the activity information.)

Comment: For the record, the above numbers are for the main site only. For the meta site, Phys.SE moderators have handled around 250 flags, while SE team members have handled around 20 flags.

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/about/team does not indicate SE team members' names now. Perhaps the page has shifted? The last archived version on the Wayback machine, https://web.archive.org/web/20170411014512/http://stackoverflow.com/company/team, gives a reasonably accurate list.