# What does the little rhombus $\blacklozenge$ behind the username mean?

Tags: support, moderators

Initially, I thought a little rhombus behind the names is a crown of topper in reputation. 
Then, I thought it signifies the site administrator

Thirdly, I thought it is written by the user himself :-) 
[image: users in P. S. E.]

which one is right?

Comment: Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6526/2451

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your second guess is closest. The diamond $\blacklozenge$ behind the username signifies [moderators](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) or [SE team members](https://stackoverflow.com/company/team). The Phys.SE moderators are listed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators).